# How to fix ADFS asking for Windows credentials after login?

Tags: adfs

We are having issues with an ADFS environment (providing authentication for a Dynamics CRM 2011 IFD installation), symptoms are as follows:

- We navigate to https://crm.domain.com:444
- We see the ADFS authentication form
- We enter valid credentials
- We are redirected to the authentication URL
- Instead of being redirected to the site, a Windows auth popup shows up, requesting credentials, stating "The server https://auth.domain.com requires a username and password" [auth.domain.com is the ADFS server]
- Any credentials we input in the popup leads to some waiting, and the popup shows up again
- If we navigate away and go back to https://crm.domain.com:444 we are *not* asked again to authenticate but the popup shows up immediately (so it seems ADFS authentication has indeed worked).

We already tried to reboot all servers:

- DC first
- DB second
- ADFS/CRM last

Customer's IT person is at a loss too (he's new to ADFS, and we are devs not IT people ourselves so out knowledge is hit and miss). Is there any known solution ?

I'll add more info/specs as needed (I'm not sure what's relevant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the authentication settings on the virtual directories have been messed about with.

Ensure /adfs virtual directory is set to anonymous only

Ensure /adfs/ls is set to anonymous and Windows Integrated Auth both only.

Comment: I forgot to follow up on this: authentication settings were indeed off, after fixing them like you suggested everything went back up. Further investigation revealed that a third party was working on some kind of unrelated web app, and was oblivious about the ADFS having stopped working ...